# iphone application splash image looks blurry on (iPhone 4) device

Tags: iphone, splash-screen

I have an Default@2x PNG image (640x920) for splash screen of our iPhone app. For some reason, it looks blurry on the device (iPhone 4) where the app is deployed, but instead on emulator it looks just fine. We are using XCode 4.2 for development. Any reasons why that's happening? And also, we assume that the image size of 640x920 should be fine (to not including the status bar - 40px in high res), correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to clean the build - an old `Default.png` may be used instead of the newer one. If that doesn't work, it might help to see the image used.

Also, as @barley said, check that the file name is `Default@2x.png`, as it is case-sensitive.

The size of `Default.png` and `Default@2x.png` should be `320x480` and `640x960`, the entire screen. This is probably because Apple allows apps to remove the status-bar at startup, but can also have resizing-effects (not sure about that).

Comment: thanks! Uninstalling the app and cleaning the build twice worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the file name matches exactly `Default@2x.png` including the case. The device is case sensitive although the simulator is not.

The math of the resolution seems correct, but since the [doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW12) says 640x960, it is also a suspicious point.